# Setting iFrame Text box value on an external webpage from parent form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iframe

I have two iframes on my `default.aspx` one loading About.aspx and other loading an external site. Is it possible to set the textbox value of the external website? 
Aspx page

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<iframe id="myFrame" runat="server" src="About.aspx" width="45%" height="400px">
</iframe>
<iframe id="myFrame1" runat="server" src="http://www.stark.co.uk/SEO/SEOLogin.aspx"
    width="45%" height="400px"></iframe>
```

script:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#MainContent_myFrame').load(function () {
            alert("Frame1");
            alert($('#MainContent_myFrame').contents().find("#MainContent_TextBox1").get());
            //alert("UserName = " + $('#MainContent_myFrame').contents().find("#TextBox1"));
            $('#MainContent_myFrame').contents().find("#MainContent_TextBox1").val("Username");
        });
        $("#MainContent_myFrame1").load(function () {
            alert("Frame2");
            alert($('#MainContent_myFrame1').get());
            var $link = $('#MainContent_myFrame1');
            alert($link.contents().find($('#Username').get()));
            $('#MainContent_myFrame1').contents().find("#Username").val("Username");
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am getting jquery error at `"$('#MainContent_myFrame1').contents().find("#Username").val("Username");"`

Error: JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: no, hopefully it is not possible due to same origin policy

Comment: is there any other method that i can set login credential to an external site of invoke there login with the valid credentials?

Comment: You can create the post request of the login form of the external site

Comment: It could be great if i have a sample code piece for that? which could be a good starter for me.